# Android : How to prevent to call again selected activity again from background to foreground after the selection of the result?

Tags: android, android-activity

I have the activity which is called after the end of the call (Hangup). See image below:

[image]

Problem is that on some devices (especially LG) i'm able to call activity back from background -> See image below:

I would like to ask, how can i deny to this behaviour?

I tried to do with some flags if activity is started form service, but it does not work.

I think that best solution could be completely end of the activity and erase this activity from history so cannot be launched again by user.

I tried to do it by this way:

```
  public void closeApp() {
    this.finish();
    }
```

But this is working only on some devices.

Could somebody tell to me how can i solve it?

Many Thanks for any help.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to use `android:excludeFromRecents` for it at your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

From [doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#exclude)

> Whether or not the task initiated by this activity should be excluded
>   from the list of recently used applications, the overview screen. That
>   is, when this activity is the root activity of a new task, this
>   attribute determines whether the task should not appear in the list of
>   recent apps. Set "true" if the task should be excluded from the list;
>   set "false" if it should be included. The default value is "false".